# Detect change on D- D+ lines

Tags: microcontroller, usb, linux, usb-device

How can i detect change  on D- and D+ (puling one or both of them high) USB lines from Linux environment?

Comment: I don't think the hardware gives you this information.

Comment: Right now this question is too short to answer.  You should add some more details about what you are trying to do and why so that people can answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attaching 1k5 pull-up resistor from 3.3V to D+/D- unknown/unrecognized USB high/low speed device would show up. You can check for this device with e.g. lsusb.

Much riskier method: most USB hosts should detect excessive current from USB power line. The problem is some other motherboards may not have overcurrent protection at all or it may not work correctly.

Other than that STM32F042F4/F6 in TSSOP20 package costs less than $3 ($1 in volume), does not require crystal and would be much more flexible.

Comment: AFAIK there is no requirement in the USB spec that requires a host to *detect* the current drawn by the slave.

Comment: Same result with lsusb after pulling D+ and D- high.http://pastebin.com/6bmyQS6t
Dmesg report error, but lsusb don't show device.
http://pastebin.com/NYJrV1CX

Comment: I wrote simple bash script to simultaneously read dmesg output and compare it with previous version. It works great.